# What language is this file generated by Mascot version 1.0 written in?

Tags: r, identification

I have been assigned a task to retrieve information from files that were processed from raw mass spectrophotometry data (file.mzML). 
These files have just ".data" as extension and when I open them, I cannot recognize the language and therefore I cannot load them into R and work on them.

The files with the .data extension are contained in this folder:

```
ftp://ftp.pride.ebi.ac.uk/pride/data/archive/2015/11/PXD000299/
```

Could someone take a look at any of the files.data and tell me the language is in (e.g. F010439)?

EDIT: these is are some snippets

Lines 1 to 10

```
MIME-Version: 1.0 (Generated by Mascot version 1.0)
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p

--gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p
Content-Type: application/x-Mascot; name="parameters"

LICENSE=Licensed to: INRA Tours, P-F Proteomique Analytique & Fonction.,Nouzilly (0085-0000003524/1), (2 processors).
MP=
NM=
COM=
```

Lines 120 to 130

```
NeutralLoss3_master=63.998285
--gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p
Content-Type: application/x-Mascot; name="unimod"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<umod:unimod xmlns:umod="http://www.unimod.org/xmlns/schema/unimod_2" majorVersion="2" minorVersion="0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.unimod.org/xmlns/schema/unimod_2 unimod_2.xsd">
  <umod:elements>
    <umod:elem avge_mass="1.00794" full_name="Hydrogen" mono_mass="1.007825035" title="H"/>
    <umod:elem avge_mass="2.014101779" full_name="Deuterium" mono_mass="2.014101779" title="2H"/>
    <umod:elem avge_mass="6.941" full_name="Lithium" mono_mass="7.016003" title="Li"/>
    <umod:elem avge_mass="12.0107" full_name="Carbon" mono_mass="12" title="C"/>
```

Comment: A file can be written by any language.  You couldn't tell a text file written by a Java program from one written using anything else.  ASCII and Unicode strings are your solution.

Comment: Trick question: Are these files binary?  (Answer: All files are binary.  A client extracts information from them using their particular lens.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that file is MIME-encoded "multi-part" file that contains (at least) two components files.

You can decode the multi-part using a MIME decoder.

The first component file looks like a simple "name=value" property file

The second component file is XML.

---

I don't know if this is relevant, but a search for `Mascot file format` gave me this reference page:

- http://www.matrixscience.com/help/data_file_help.html

Also, there were some interesting hits when I searched for `parser "x-mascot"` and `parser mascot`.  If you can find an existing parser, then you may be able to save yourself implementation effort.